# Saving an int in iOS app

Tags: ios, int

I'm made a simple ipad game, but I need to know how to record the highest score and keep it even after the app closes.
Is there a simple way to record this from the main view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely!  Use NSUserDefaults

Specifically:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:YOUR_HIGHSCORE_VARIABLE forKey:@"highScore"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Then when you want to retrieve the high score:

```
NSInteger highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScore"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSUserDefaults`:

Save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:yourValue forKey:@"YourKeyString"];
```

Restore:

```
NSInteger yourValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:"YourKeyString"];
```

But that isn't a great idea, not terrible for a single item, but if extended to several items it is better to use another approach such as `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, Property lists, CoreData, etc.